# How to remove a menu entry that has no executable

Tags: xubuntu, menu, whisker

How can I remove a menu entry that has been orphaned? The executable command tied to it has been deleted from the system.

I am looking at it with menulibre, but the entry doesn't show up. I am running Xubuntu 16.04 with the whisker menu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this was to recreate the exact path structure and names that the missing menu entry was complaining about and from there it is possible to manually delete it with menulibre.